# Partitioning data in eventhub using capture

Tags: azure-eventhub

Is it possible to capture the eventhub data in adls gen 2 in hive folder partitioning format like date=xyz using the capture feature on the portal??

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning is a feature of ADLS store and it is abstracted from Event Hubs capture. Thus, I think you should be able to configure partitions just fine.